# Simultaneously traversing of List by 2 Variables

Tags: python, list

I am working on a code in which I am traversing a list, for example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

There are 8 elements(assuming that 'a' will always have even numbers) and I want to access 2 at a time, means the loop will execute 4 times. Every time the variable will increase by 2, like the odd and even numbers

```
b =1
for i range(len(a)/2):
    print(a[2*b-1],a[2*b])
    b += 1
```

the output will be an error because list index starts from 0 and ends on 3 and the list index will be out of range. this will not print 1 and 8 what do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most recent version of your code the minimal fix (most close to the original solution)

```
b = 0
for i in range(len(a)/2):
    print(a[2*b], a[2*b+1])
    b += 1
```

A better solution is

```
for i in range(len(a)/2):
     print(a[2*i], a[2*i+1])
```

To handle even length use range((len(a) + 1) /2)

Comment: yes actually the i is wrong there i have to place a different variable can you it now

Comment: the new version makes no sense at all. Well you can add increment of b, b += 1 but it is simpler with i?

Comment: do not forget missing in keyword in the loop, decrement index even one more,print(a[2*b-2],a[2*b - 1])  and make clear in the question what was original question and which result worked for you. That will  looks stupid but will work

Comment: yes, this works correctly, but now what is the use of 'b' here, in the upper solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think changing `2*i-1` to `2*i+1`. That's a simple question.

Comment: then can you please add the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate two-by-two without having to worry about indexing by creating a single iterator with `iter` and then `zip` it with itself.

This is similar to the [`grouper` function from itertools' recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and has the advantage of being able to treat any iterarable, including non-indexed ones such as generators.

```
def iter_two_by_two(it):
    it = iter(it)
    yield from zip(it, it)

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for pair in iter_two_by_two(a):
    print(pair)
```

### Output

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
(7, 8)
```